# Dynamic switching of radio: Change between wireless protocols in the 2.4GHz

Tags: wifi, protocol, transceiver

I want a radio core (transceiver). I want it to work on both the protocols.

> 802.15.4 and 802.11

I already know of some SoC which has both the PHY layers to work that up. http://www.gainspan.com/docs2/GS2000-PB.pdf

Is it possible to switch between them in someway with a single transceiver?
I'm thinking of a low energy application with WiFi used rarely and communication done using 802.15.4 (probably 6LoWPAN)

Comment: What exactly is your question? The SoC you showed has the capability you're requesting, is there something that you're trying to do which it doesn't provide?

Comment: I m looking at such alternatives or make one by myself using a generic chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go low-level enough, anything is possible. Your best bet would be to stick with an old WiFi standard -- like 802.11b -- which is comparatively simple to implement. But when I say "comparatively simple," keep in mind we're still talking direct-sequence spread-spectrum and a rather complicated coding scheme (I think it's called [complementary-code keying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_code_keying)). You'll need to find a transceiver that supports that technology along with the simpler GFSK modulation and frequency-hopping that 802.15.4 uses. That might be more difficult than you think. Then you'll have to write a WiFi stack and an 802.15.4 stack. Sounds terrifying... good luck!

Comment: would you say gainspan's GS2000 SoC is relatively simpler?

Comment: @akrv, I would say so, it seems to handle a lot of it for you.

Comment: 802.15.4 doesn't use GFSK, it uses BPSK, with DSSS (Spreading factor of 8). Bluetooth uses GFSK with FHSS.

Comment: For WiFi, a dedicated clock recovery circuit is also helpful.